# Recursive call for JSON in swift 3

Tags: json, recursion, swift3, xcode8

I have a response that looks like this

```
{
"id": 3,
"parent_id": 1,
"name": "QuickStart Intelligence",
"is_active": true,
"position": 2,
"level": 1,
"product_count": 590,
"children_data": [
    {
        "id": 53,
        "parent_id": 3,
        "name": "Find Training",
        "is_active": true,
        "position": 1,
        "level": 2,
        "product_count": 9,
        "children_data": [
            {
                "id": 58,
                "parent_id": 53,
                "name": "Career Paths",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 1,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": [
                    {
                        "id": 123,
                        "parent_id": 58,
                        "name": "Business Productivity",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 1,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 245,
                        "children_data": []
                    },

                    {
                        "id": 70,
                        "parent_id": 58,
                        "name": "Creative & Design",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 3,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 43,
                        "children_data": []
                    },

                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 57,
                "parent_id": 53,
                "name": "Technology",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 2,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 1,
                "children_data": [
                    {
                        "id": 162,
                        "parent_id": 57,
                        "name": "Microsoft",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 6,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 183,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 164,
                        "parent_id": 57,
                        "name": "Adobe",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 8,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 34,
                        "children_data": []
                    }
                  ]
               }
        {
                "id": 100,
                "parent_id": 53,
                "name": "Certifications",
                "is_active": true,
                "position": 3,
                "level": 3,
                "product_count": 0,
                "children_data": [
                    {
                        "id": 112,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Microsoft SQL Server 2012",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 1,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 113,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Windows Server 2012 Microsoft Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 2,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 114,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Visual Studio Microsoft Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 3,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 115,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "SharePoint 2013 Microsoft Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 4,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 116,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Private Cloud Microsoft Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 5,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 117,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Exchange Server 2013 Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 6,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 118,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Lync Server 2013 Microsoft Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 7,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 119,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Windows 8 Microsoft Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 8,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 120,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Microsoft System Center Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 9,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 121,
                        "parent_id": 100,
                        "name": "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Certifications",
                        "is_active": true,
                        "position": 10,
                        "level": 4,
                        "product_count": 0,
                        "children_data": []
                    }
                ]
            }
```

It goes on like that. I have initialized some variables in my class Categories like this

```
var categoryId = Int()
var parentId = Int()
var categoryName = String()
var isCategoryActive = Bool()
var categoryPostion = Int()
var categoryLevel = Int()
var categoryChildCount = Int()
var childArray = [Categories]()
```

I know that it should be done with a recursive call but somehow i am unable to wrap my head around the solution. I've tried looking on overflow but couldn't find anything relevant. this is how i am casting the json

```
   class func getUserFromJson(_ jsonString: String) -> Categories {
        let category = Categories()
    do {
         let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

        if let id = dic.object(forKey: "id") as? Int {
            category.categoryId = id
        }
        if let parentId = dic.object(forKey: "parent_id") as? Int {
            category.parentId = parentId
        }
        if let name = dic.object(forKey: "name") as? String {
            category.categoryName = name
        }
        if let isActive = dic.object(forKey: "is_active") as? Bool {
            category.isCategoryActive = isActive
        }
        if let position = dic.object(forKey: "position") as? Int {
            category.categoryPostion = position
        }
        if let level = dic.object(forKey: "level") as? Int {
            category.categoryLevel = level
        }
        if let productCount = dic.object(forKey: "product_count") as? Int {
            category.categoryChildCount = productCount
        }


    }
    catch {

    }

    return category

}
```

How would i parse the children_data which is an array and has many children and again those children have children as you can see and some of them are empty so i need to check for that as well.

Comment: copy your json data and use json viewer .It would make it easy to parse your data   http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 0):

go like this.

```
let childrenData = dic["children_data"] as? NSArray
{
for data in childrenData
{
let child_dic = data as! NSDictionary
//Here Your Code.
}
}
```

You can use same for child of child.

Comment: then i would again have to do jsonSerialization call with do catch block to cast the elements in child_dic dictionary? or how should i use the objects i've already parsed to assign values to the child_dic key-value pairs?

Comment: You just have to use. No need to do jsonSerialization again

Comment: pardon me, i don't really understand what you're saying :( I understand i would get all the dictionaries via data through iteration and later i can cast it as a dictionary then what do i need to do to make that call again or set the values of id, parent id etc ?

Comment: let child_id = child_dic["id"] 
Like this you can get values.